# Change marker position with click on map layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to be able to have a user click on a geoJSON layer in a leaflet map, then display a marker with a custom icon where they clicked. If they click again on the layer, I want to remove the original marker, then add a new marker on the latest click location.

I can get this to work using the default icon from Leaflet, but when I specify a custom icon, it fails, returning the error: `TypeError: t.icon.createIcon is not a function`.

This works:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
        lng = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];                  
        mymap.on('click', function (e) {
            if (marker) {
                mymap.removeLayer(marker);
            }
            marker = new L.Marker([lat,lng]).addTo(mymap);
        });
    });
}
```

But this does not (only adding `{icon: marker}`:

```
var marker = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evantdailey/map_testing/master/dot.png',
    iconSize: [20,20],
});
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
        lng = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];                  
        mymap.on('click', function (e) {
            if (marker) {
                mymap.removeLayer(marker);
            }
            marker = new L.Marker([lat,lng], {icon: marker}).addTo(mymap);
        });
    });
}
```

Any guess what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong, and it's a good lesson in carefully naming variables. The original `marker` variable (now `markerIcon`) was getting reassigned to the actual thing that was on the map. That worked for the first click, but then on subsequent clicks `marker` was referencing the thing on the map, not the icon definition, so JS got confused.

Adding `var marker;` and renaming the icon definition to `markerIcon` resolved the confusion.

This now works:

```
var marker;
var markerIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evantdailey/map_testing/master/dot.png',
    iconSize: [20,20],
});    
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
        lng = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];          
        mymap.on('click', function (e) {
            if (marker) {
                mymap.removeLayer(marker);
            }
            marker = new L.Marker([lat,lng], {icon: markerIcon}).addTo(mymap);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You can _accept_ your own answer, so that people know your issue is solved.

Comment: SO requires that I wait two days to accept, but I will when I can.

Comment: ouch, let's hope you will get more privileges soon… :-) nice to document your findings anyway!

Comment: is it necessary to remove the marker then add new marker?
is it possible to just update the marker position?